# `docker run -v`: Copy all files from container to host?

Tags: docker

I have the following command:
`docker run -it -v ~/Desktop:/var/task mylambda bash`

From my understanding, this command here will mount a volume so all files inside `/var/task` within my container will be copied to `~/Desktop`. But that's not the case. Do I misunderstand that command? How do I otherwise get `/var/task/lambdatest.zip` to my localhost?

Answer (score 1):

It works the other way around.

The command you have mounts `~/Desktop` (usually the command requires an absolute path) into the container such that the container's directory `/var/task` is the content of your desktop. This will have the consequence of mounting the `~/Desktop` over any content existing within the container's `/var/task` directory and so `/var/task/lambdatest.zip` would not be accessible to the container.

You want to use `docker cp` command:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

Answer (score 0):

You are using bind mounts. This is actually their behaviour. Your goal can be achived with volumes.

```
docker run -it -v a_docker_managed_volume:/var/task mylambda bash
```

Have a look at the reference https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/